# Проблема с сохранением пути до медиафайлов в string массив для дальнейшего использования

Tags: c#, массивы, xamarin, изображения

Ни в какую не сохраняется [path](/questions/tagged/path) до нескольких изображений, выбранных с галереи с помощью [crossmedia](/questions/tagged/crossmedia) в массив для его дальнейшего использования [path](/questions/tagged/path) каждого выбранного изображения.

```
async void getPhotoBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
            {
                _image = new Image[] { img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6 };
                stringImg = new String[_image.Length];
                foreach (Image i in _image)
                {
                    if (i.Source == null)
                    {
                        photo = new MediaFile[] { p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6 };
                        for (int j = 0; j < _image.Length; j++)
                        {
                            photo[j] = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
                            stringImg[j] = photo[j].Path;
                            if (photo != null)
                            {
                                i.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(photo[j].Path);
                                return;
                            }
                            else if (photo == null)
                            {
                                return;
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

В массив stringImg прилетает только последний [path](/questions/tagged/path) выбранного фото, остальные элементы массива остаются [null](/questions/tagged/null). В чем косяк? уже второй день голову ломаю...

Comment: Что-то вы намудрили с кодом. Сначала вы создали массив (не пустой), переопределяете его элементы, а потом проверяете на `null` соответствие. Возможно пригодится вам [пример](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/mt742868.aspx) с MSDN по работе с CrossMedia плагином.

Comment: С одной фотографией вопросов не возникает, а вот с массивом из 6 фотографий проблема. img1 и тд определены в [tag:xaml], поэтому массив не пустой.